# Can you search for base64 with grep?

Tags: grep, base64

Is it possible to search for Base64 strings with grep?  Say I have a list of text files and I want to find all the Base64 strings contained in them; is there any way to search for them?  I mean I know they usually end with `=` or `==` and they also have sequences of bytes which relate to what [letters they are encoded as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table) within the base64 string.  But as for searching for them in general (without knowing anything about what is encoded) I don't really know how to do so.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate for [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418316/how-can-i-find-php-files-with-long-base64-strings). Try the answer given on this request.

Comment: @perko I think it depends on the version of grep you're using.  I was using git-bash for Windows and the answer in that duplicate didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look for strings which are composed only of valid Base64 characters, with the correct structure and padding if necessary:

```
grep -E '[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)'
```

This looks for any number of sequences of four Base64 characters, followed by either another four, or three with a single padding character, or two with two padding characters.